# Ruby Koans: Why convert list of symbols to strings

Tags: ruby

I'm referring to this test in about_symbols.rb in Ruby Koans
https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/src/about_symbols.rb#L26

```
def test_method_names_become_symbols
  symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
  assert_equal true, symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
end


  # THINK ABOUT IT:
  #
  # Why do we convert the list of symbols to strings and then compare
  # against the string value rather than against symbols?
```

Why exactly do we have to convert that list into strings first?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This has to do with how symbols work.  For each symbol, only one of it actually exists.  Behind the scenes, a symbol is just a number referred to by a name (starting with a colon).  Thus, when comparing the equality of two symbols, you're comparing object identity and *not* the content of the identifier that refers to this symbol.

If you were to do the simple test **:test == "test"**, it will be false.  So, if you were to gather all of the symbols defined thus far into an array, you would need to convert them to strings first before comparing them.  You can't do this the opposite way (convert the string you want to compare into a symbol first) because doing that would create the single instance of that symbol and "pollute" your list with the symbol you're testing for existence.

This is a bit of an odd one, because you have to test for the presence of a symbol without accidentally creating that symbol during the test.  You usually don't see code like that.

Comment: Note that a better way of doing this safely is to assign the output of `Symbol.all_symbols` to a variable, then test for inclusion. Symbols are faster at comparison, and you're avoiding converting thousands of symbols into strings.

Comment: That still has the problem of creating the symbol which can't be destroyed.  Any future tests for that symbol will be ruined.  But this is just a Koan, it doesn't have to make much sense or be fast, just demonstrate how symbols work.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. If we're searching for existence of a symbol, why are we specifying a string argument to ``include?`` If we specified ``:test_method_names_become_symbols`` we wouldn't have to convert all those symbols to strings.

Comment: Isaac, because of the issue identified, which is that specifying `:test_method_names_become_symbols` in the comparison will create it, so the comparison will always be true. By converting `all_symbols` to strings and comparing strings, we can distinguish whether the symbol existed prior to the comparison.

Comment: @Stephen wouldnt the array from `Symbols.all_symbols` be an older array, which wouldnt contain that symbol? since that symbol would have been created after the array was created? Or is that function returning a reference to the main array and not a copy? Or is it an order of evaluation thing? or implementation dependant?

Comment: @KarthikT Yep, I believe the symbol is being evaluated before the include? method is being invoked (eager/strict evaluation).

Comment: So much I don't understand. If I do >> array_of_symbols=Symbol.all_symbols, then >> array_of_symbols.include?(:not_yet_used), I get false, and I get true for something that was defined, so I don't understand why the conversion to strings is necesary.

Comment: @codenoob : Yes you are correct and we can compare symbols like that. But if you ran Symbols.all_symbols again, you ll see :not_yet_used being created. so the point is if we tried to check the symbols directly without using temp variable, then it ll always be true

Comment: What I took from the koan and this discussion is that we want to avoid introducing _anything_ in tests that might invalidate other tests. The purpose of the test is to check the output of your code, not artifacts from other tests. Creating symbols in a test pollutes all_symbols; it's no longer a valid representation of the code you are testing. Ergo, it's better practice to use string comparisons when testing for the existence of symbols.

Answer (score 91):

Because if you do:

```
assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:test_method_names_become_symbols)
```

It may (depending on your ruby implementation) automatically be true, because `:test_method_names_become_symbols` creates the symbol. See [this bug report](https://github.com/neo/ruby_koans/issues/22).

Comment: So the accepted answer is the wrong one (or so it seems to me).

Comment: Isaac, the other answer isn't wrong but it's not explained as concisely. for sure. Anyway, you can verify what Andrew's saying with the following:

assert_equal true, Symbol.all_symbols.include?(:abcdef)

This will always pass (at least, it does for me) regardless of the symbol. I guess one lesson is, don't try to use the presence/absence of symbols as a boolean flag.

Comment: Looking at this question, which still interests me, 2 years later, I really appreciate this answer, and the comments. I think Isaac is right this is the answer most clearly explaining why the conversion to strings may be the way to go, though I think you could put the intermediary step (store all the symbols before the compar) in to make it work better.

Comment: WOW, that's deep!

Answer (score 5):

Both answers above are correct, but in light of Karthik's question above I thought I would post a test that illustrates how one might accurately pass a symbol to the `include` method

```
def test_you_create_a_new_symbol_in_the_test
  array_of_symbols = []
  array_of_symbols << Symbol.all_symbols
  all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols.map {|x| x}
  assert_equal false, array_of_symbols.include?(:this_should_not_be_in_the_symbols_collection)  #this works because we stored all symbols in an array before creating the symbol :this_should_not_be_in_the_symbols_collection in the test
  assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:this_also_should_not_be_in_the_symbols_collection) #This is the case noted in previous answers...here we've created a new symbol (:this_also_should_not_be_in_the_symbols_collection) in the test and then mapped all the symbols for comparison. Since we created the symbol before querying all_symbols, this test passes.
end
```

An additional note about the Koans:  make use of `puts` statements as well as custom tests if you don't understand anything. For instance, if you see:

```
string = "the:rain:in:spain"
words = string.split(/:/)
```

and have no idea what `words` might be, add the line

```
puts words
```

and run `rake` at the command line. Likewise, tests like the one I added above can be helpful in terms of understanding some of the nuances of Ruby.

Comment: Looking at this question, which still interests me, 2 years later, I really appreciate this answer, and the comments.