# Checking if symbol is present in the array with include?

Tags: ruby, symbols

Trying Ruby with the help of [Ruby Koans](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans). There is following test there:

```
def test_method_names_become_symbols
  symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }
  assert_equal __, symbols_as_strings.include?("test_method_names_become_symbols")
end

# THINK ABOUT IT:
#
# Why do we convert the list of symbols to strings and then compare
# against the string value rather than against symbols?
```

I tried to do the same thing in the irb console and it returned `false` for the undefined method. But then I tried the same in some `test.rb` file and `true` was returned to both existing and unexisting methods.

Sample code:

```
def test_method
end
symbols = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x }
puts symbols.include?(:test_method) # returns true in both cases
puts symbols.include?(:test_method_nonexistant) # returns false in irb, true if executed directly
```

The questions are: why do we convert symbols to strings in such case and why there are different results in irb and normal file?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Koans: Why convert list of symbols to strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686097/ruby-koans-why-convert-list-of-symbols-to-strings)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us go through a slightly modified version of your test code as it is seen by `irb` and as a stand alone script:

```
def test_method;end
symbols = Symbol.all_symbols # This is already a "fixed" array, no need for map
puts symbols.include?(:test_method)
puts symbols.include?('test_method_nonexistent'.to_sym)
puts symbols.include?(:test_method_nonexistent)
eval 'puts symbols.include?(:really_not_there)'
```

When you try this in `irb`, each line will be parsed and evaluated before the next line. When you hit the second line, `symbols` will contain `:test_method` because `def test_method;end` has already been evaluated. But, the `:test_method_nonexistent` symbol hasn't been seen anywhere when we hit line 2 so lines 4 and 5 will say "false". Line 6 will, of course, give us another false because `:really_not_there` doesn't exist until after `eval` returns. So `irb` says this:

```
true
false
false
false
```

If you run this as a Ruby script, things happen in a slightly different order. First Ruby will parse the script into an internal format that the Ruby VM understands and then it goes back to the first line and starts executing the script. When the script is being parsed, the `:test_method` symbol will exist after the first line is parsed and `:test_method_nonexistent` will exist after the fifth line has been parsed; so, before the script runs, two of the symbols we're interested in are known. When we hit line six, Ruby just sees an `eval` and a string but it doesn't yet know that the `eval` cause a symbol to come into existence.

Now we have two of our symbols (`:test_method` and `:test_method_nonexistent`) and a simple string that, when fed to `eval`, will create a symbol (`:really_not_there`). Then we go back to the beginning and the VM starts running code. When we run line 2 and cache our symbols array, both `:test_method` and `:test_method_nonexistent` will exist and appear in the `symbols` array because the parser created them. So lines 3 through 5:

```
puts symbols.include?(:test_method)
puts symbols.include?('test_method_nonexistent'.to_sym)
puts symbols.include?(:test_method_nonexistent)
```

will print "true". Then we hit line 6:

```
eval 'puts symbols.include?(:really_not_there)'
```

and "false" is printed because `:really_not_there` is created by the `eval` at run-time rather than during parsing. The result is that Ruby says:

```
true
true
true
false
```

If we add this at the end:

```
symbols = Symbol.all_symbols
puts symbols.include?('really_not_there'.to_sym)
```

Then we'll get another "true" out of both `irb` and the stand-alone script because `eval` will have created `:really_not_there` and we will have grabbed a fresh copy of the symbol list.

Comment: Excellent breakdown on the different behavior of irb the regular interpreter. +1

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have to convert symbols to strings when checking for existence of a symbol is that it will always return true otherwise. The argument being passed to the `include?` method gets evaluated first, so if you pass it a symbol, the a new symbol is instantiated and added into the heap, so `Symbol.all_symbols` does, in fact, have a copy of the symbol.

```
Symbol.all_symbols.include? :the_crow_flies_at_midnight #=> true
```

However, converting thousands of symbols to strings for comparison (which is much faster with symbols) is a poor solution. A better method would be to change the order that these statements get evaluated:

```
symbols = Symbol.all_symbols
symbols.include? :the_crow_flies_at_midnight #=> false
```

This "snapshot" of what symbols are in the dictionary is taken before our tested symbol is inserted onto the heap, so even though our argument exists on the heap at the time the `include?` method is called, we are getting the result we expect.

I don't know why it isn't working in your IRB console. Perhaps you mistyped.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But why would that new symbol appear in my `symbols` array. It was formed at some point and why would it change? Also I am certain I haven't mistyped and you can try it yourself.